# Calling an action to update local storage (without API call) - redux persist, react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to dispatch an action in redux sagas to add an id to a local store:

```
import { call, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { BENEFITS } from '../actions/types';


function* addBenefitIdToViewedList(action){
    const id = action.payload.isClaimable? 'c'+ action.payload.id : 's'+action.payload.id;
    console.log(id)
    console.log(action)

    console.log(yield call({type: BENEFITS.VIEWED_LIST.ADD, rootAction:action}));
  }

  export default function*() {
    yield takeEvery(BENEFITS.VIEWED_LIST.POST, addBenefitIdToViewedList);
  }
```

**I think the problem is the "yield call" - should I use sth different?**

When I debug it, the BENEFITS.VIEWED_LIST.POST is called and the id and action is printed accordingly. However, the BENEFITS.VIEWED_LIST.ADD is not called. I need to call, so that reducer can update the store.

Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to schedule the dispatching of an action to the store you need to use [put](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction) as such: `yield put(action)` instead of call that just calls a function.

Comment: I also forgot to add the reducer to the combineReducers(). Thank you! :)